# ¿Como tomar el valor de dos selects con el mismo nombre y que php los reciba?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Como podría tomar el valor de dos `selects` para que `PHP` me los reciba para poder realizar un `foreach` e insertarlo en la base de datos? ya que lo que se requiere es que un usuario tenga dos roles al mismo tiempo.

es decir que en mi tabla detalle pueda insertar al mismo tiempo el id del usuario y el rol el cual quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
detalle_id_usuario: 1
detalle_id_usuario: 1
detalle_id_rol: 1 (Administrador)
detalle_id_rol: 5 (coordinador)
```

algo asi es como se debería de insertar al mismo tiempo pero no se de que manera...agradecería la colaboración.

**HTML**

```
<select name="rol_usuario">
<option value="1">Administrador</option>
<option value="2">usuario</option>
</select>

<select name="rol_usuario">
<option value="3">jefe de area</option>
<option value="4">tecnico</option>
<option value="5">coordinador</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Si intentas mandar dos `select` (o `input`) con el mismo `name` va a pasar una de dos cosas: o te dará un error o solo tomará el primero.
Mejor primero revisa bien lo que quieres hacer y haz un diseño adecuado, tanto de base de datos como de interfaz de usuario.

Comment: Hola @KroneauxSchneider gracias por el interes, bueno, por eso creo que explico que la idea es poder tomar dos valores el cual se van a insertar al mismo tiempo, por eso realizo dos selects para poder tomar esos valores que se insertaran con el mismo usuario pero con diferente rol.

Comment: Pon dos selects distintos y no mandes guardar el registro inmediatamente, pon un `button` de acción para guardar toda la información al mismo tiempo. Insisto, revisa tu planteamiento (no el de aquí sino el que estás trabajando).

Answer (score 2):

solo trata la variable en php como un `array`, ya que este viajará al servidor de la siguiente manera.

```
[POST]
$_POST => rol_usuario { "valor_campo1", "valor_campo2"  }
```

para lo que puedes usar un:

```
count($_POST['rol_usuario']) // retornará 2 en este ejemplo
```